# List of index values for repeating segments

Tags: python, list

How do I create a new list containing the only the beginning index number of where the segment of all the True elements within the `main_list` consecutively repeat for at least 3 times or more (`min_segment=3`)?

```
> main_list = [True, True, False, False, True, True, True, True, True, False, False, True, True,True]
```

The expected answer is:

```
> true_index = [4,11]
> #first repeating segment that contains 3 or more True elements starts at index 4, whilst the second segment starts at index 11
> #the repeating segment at index 0 contains 2 True elements which is less than `min_segment=3` so is excluded
```

**I need a simple code that does not require the use of numpy or groupby.**

So far, my code shows the starting index numbers for all repeating True segments and does not account for the condition to only include segments with at least 3 or more True elements (`min_segment=3`).

```
> i = 0
> true_index = []
> while i < len(disorder_status):
    if disorder_status[i]: # if True
        true_index.append(i)
        if False in disorder_status[i:]:
            i = 1 + disorder_status.index(False, i)
        else:
            break # all remaining items in list are True
    else:
        i += 1
```

This gives me an incorrect answer of:

```
> true_index = [0,4,11]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding a consecutive 'True' boolean values in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59236607/finding-a-consecutive-true-boolean-values-in-a-list)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
main_list = [True, True, False, False, True, True, True, True, True, False, False, True, True,True]
min_segment=3
# find all indices with at least min_segment true values
indices = [i for i in range(len(main_list)) if sum(main_list[i:i+min_segment]) >=min_segment]
# get the result
res = [indices[i] for i in range(len(indices)) if indices[i] != indices[i-1]+1]
```

Comment: I tested this and it worked only for segments are greater than 3. But the condition is that the repeating segments be **equal** or more than 3 consecutive True elements.

Answer (score 0):

Your current solution doesn't check if the first found True value actually belongs to a set of at least 3.

I modified your code, to reflect the changes:

```
main_list = [True, True, False, False, True, True, True, True, True, False, False, True, True,True]
true_index = []

i = 0
#No need to check last 2 values, since they can't possibly form a segment
while i < len(main_list)-2:
  if main_list[i]:
    if False in main_list[i:]:
      next_false = main_list.index(False, i)
      if next_false - i >= 3: #chain of True values is longer or equal 3
        true_index.append(i)
      i = 1 + next_false
    else:
      true_index.append(i)
      break # all remaining items in list are True
  else:
    i += 1
```

Comment: I tested this with different variation of main_list and saw that if `main_list = [True, True, False, False, True, True, True, True, True, False, False, True, True]` , it gives `true_index = [4,11]`. However, the repeating segment at index 11 contains only 2 True elements so it should not be in the `true_index` list.

Comment: @Vicky I've modified the code, to account for that. The last 2 values can't possibly be a valid segment, so they are skipped.

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
from itertools import groupby

out = []
index = 0
for g,k in groupby(main_list):
    k = list(k)
    if g == True and len(k) >=3:
        out.append(index)
    index += len(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

A functional solution:

```
from itertools import groupby

def get_first_index_of_repeating_segments(lst, pattern = True, repeat = 3):
    group_pattern_counts = [(group[0], len(group)) for group in [list(g) for _, g in groupby(lst)]]
    
    return [sum(map(lambda gpc: gpc[1], group_pattern_counts[:i])) for i, p_c in enumerate(group_pattern_counts) if p_c[0] == pattern and p_c[1] >= repeat]
```

Example:

```
lst = [True, True, False, False, True, True, \
             True, True, True, False, False, True, True, True]

print(get_first_index_of_repeating_segments(last))
```

Output:

```
[4, 11]
```